# Excel VBA Filter by date

Tags: excel, vba

Upon searching thru google and youtube about filtering date it shows only that filter by range date (initial date and last date). Is it possible to create a filter with only one date? Im trying to filter and search that to my created excel VBA but it gives me a Runtime syntax error. As for my search button my only code is to call the list box data (call list_box_data) sorry im new and still learning hope someone helps me thanks!

```
`Sub list_box_data()

Dim sh As Worksheet
Set sh = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Support")

sh.Cells.ClearContents
Dim cnn As New ADODB.Connection
Dim rst As New ADODB.Recordset

Dim qry As String, i As Integer
Dim n As Long

If Me.cb_filter.Value = "ALL" Then
        qry = "Select * FROM TBL_CA"
'ElseIf Me.cb_filter.Value = "Status" Then
       ' qry = "SELECT * FROM TBL_CA WHERE
Else
        qry = "SELECT * FROM TBL_CA WHERE " & Me.cb_filter.Value & " 
LIKE '%" & Me.tb_search.Value & "%'"
End If
  
cnn.Open "Provider = Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" & 
ThisWorkbook.Path & "\Database.ACCDB"

rst.Open qry, cnn, adOpenKeyset, adLockOptimistic

sh.Range("A2").CopyFromRecordset rst

For i = 1 To rst.Fields.Count
    sh.Cells(1, i).Value = rst.Fields(i - 1).Name
Next i

rst.Close
cnn.Close

'========================================
With Me.data_list
    .ColumnCount = 15
    .ColumnHeads = True
    .ColumnWidths = "80,80,80,80,160,100,80,60,140,140,160,140,140,80,"

n = sh.Range("A" & Application.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

If n > 1 Then
    .RowSource = "Support!A2:N" & n
Else
    .RowSource = "Support!A2:N2"
End If

End With

If (n - 1) < 2 Then
    Me.lbl_record_count.Caption = (n - 1) & " Record"
ElseIf (n - 1) > 1 Then
    Me.lbl_record_count.Caption = (n - 1) & " Records"
    
End If


    

End Sub`
```

[image: img1]

Comment: Where is your code?

Comment: @dwirony

`Private Sub btn_Search_Click()
 
    Call list_box_data
    
End Sub`

This is just my code since im filtering other types like "status" and etc.

Comment: Okay, so you call another subroutine... where is that code? You need to include the code causing your error in your question in order for us to help you.

Comment: @dwirony

Hi! sorry you mean the code for list box? Already edit the post and include the code for list box

Comment: @dwirony 
And i got error on this line `rst.Open qry, cnn, adOpenKeyset, adLockOptimistic`

Comment: Before that line, can you please put a `Debug.Print qry` line and let us know what that returns? You might need to hit Ctrl + G on your keyboard to open up the immediate window. It almost looks like you're missing a closing apostrophe in your `LIKE` clause, but it appears to be there in your code...

Comment: @dwirony this shows when i hit ctrl+G `Select * FROM TBL_CA
SELECT * FROM TBL_CA WHERE Received Date LIKE '%28-Jul-2022%'`

Comment: How is `Received Date` a field name? shouldn't it have an underscore in it?

Comment: @dwirony Ohhhh wait, yeah column name is "Received_Date".